# How I can make $(document).click() execute earlier that the $(element).click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    $('.shoppingCartPopup').hide();
  });

  function showShoppingCartPopup() {
    $('.shoppingCartPopup').show();
  }
</script>
```

I have anchor element tag where `onclick="showShoppingCartPopup()"`. The problem is when I am clicking on that anchor the popup is not become visible because $(document).click() is executing after $(element).click() and the popup immediately becomes invisible. When I am commenting

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
  $('.shoppingCartPopup').hide();
});
```

section, popup is getting visible without any problem. So what should I do to achieve what I need? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why you are using inline event handler?

Comment: On `document`'s click you can check `event.target` is not your anchor. So, your element will be hidden only if you click outside the anchor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/), it prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree. Hence document click handler will not be executed.

Pass `event` to handler i.e. `onclick="showShoppingCartPopup(event)"`

```
function showShoppingCartPopup(event){
    event.stopPropagation()
    $('.shoppingCartPopup').show();
}
```

Note: I would recommend to you to get rid of inline event handler and use unobtrusive event handler.

As per comment *can't pass any event there*

As you can give an identifier or CSS class to anchor element to identify it. then you can check if the element which is clicked is not the anchor

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('a.myClass').length == 0) {
        $('.shoppingCartPopup').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Saptal, this was the behaviour I was expected, but unfortunatelly I am using showShoppingCartPopup() also in other place in Wicket listener so I can't pass any event there.

Comment: @Saptal yes I can

Comment: @ArsenAlexanyan, Updated answer

Comment: Thanks @Saptal! This idea worked great for me. I am choosing this as the right answer. Additionally I have added check to not hide the popup if the click is on the popup itself like this 
.. && $(e.target).parents('.shoppingCartPopup').length == 0

Answer (score 1):

use event.stopPropagation() as the last line of your method, it will stop the event to propagate to dom.

```
function showShoppingCartPopup(e) {
    $('.shoppingCartPopup').show();
    e.stopPropagation()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

On you `document`'s click, you could check that you've not clicked on your anchor. So, on anchor's click you show the cart. If you click elsewhere, hide the cart.

Note that otherwise, you could use [event.stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to stop propagation in the DOM in [bubbling](https://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing) phase.

See [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

```
<!-- Your anchor -->
<a id="my-anchor" href=#" onclick="showShoppingCartPopup()">Show</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {  
        /*
         * On click anywhere on document, this code will be
         * executed.
         * If your target is your anchor, it does nothing. Otherwise,
         * it execute your action.
         */
        $(document).on('click', function(e) {
            //IE 6-8 compatibility
            var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
            //Stop execution if you clicked on your anchor
            if (target.id === "my-anchor") {
                return;
            }
            //Code below is executed only if your target is NOT #my-anchor
            $('.shoppingCartPopup').hide();
        };

        /*
         * On your anchor click, execute this action
         */
        function showShoppingCartPopup() {
            $('.shoppingCartPopup').show();
        }   
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What if the e.target.id is other anchor? I wish to hide my popup when clicking anywhere outside of the popup.

Comment: You can have only one element in your DOM with id = "anchor". So, if you click on this anchor the document's click will do nothing. But if you click anywhere in document but this anchor, it will hide your popup.